# Opencv - align sample image and testing image

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I have been in the project of testing the images of sample products compared with a sample product image. I have come up with two approaches but there are problems encountered in each approach.

Method 1. Remove Background, Realign images according to features and then find the difference of two images by subtraction.
Problem: I am thinking about using template matching to extract the region of interest and save as a new picture. However, is it possible to use template matching to extract? I saw the sample provided by opencv can make a frame or rectangle around the matched object. So, it seems feasible for me to make it at the center in the new picture. If it is possible, what is the way of making a square matched as the center of a new picture? It seems a bit difficult as the matched rectangle may not be horizontal.

Method 2. Cascade Classifier Training: it seems I can train the classifier to know what bad images are and what good images are. 
Problem: However, from the classifier detection sample by opencv, it was used to compare during a video. Is it possible to do so on images? Also, how could I adjust the sample error or the precision of the classifier detection?

If you have any other feasible suggestions, please kindly give me some advices on them. Thanks for your kind attention!!